# Why does an inner join with sql variables takes 5 to 7 seconds more

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, inner-join

I have following join in which I hard coded TimeStamp (DateTime). This takes 2 - 3 seconds.

```
SELECT *  
FROM Prod_Units ProdUnits
INNER JOIN PUIDLIST_CTE PUIDCTE ON ProdUnits.PU_Id IN (PUIDCTE.PU_ID)  
INNER JOIN  Orders ORD ON ORD.TimeStamp BETWEEN '25 AUG 2017' AND '26 AUG 2017' 
                       AND ProdUnits.PU_Id IN (ORD.PU_Id)
```

But If I create two variables and do exact same thing , it take 7 to 9 seconds!!

```
DECLARE @STARTTIME DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDTIME DATETIME 

SET @STARTTIME = '25 AUG 2017'
SET @ENDTIME = '26 AUG 2017'

SELECT *  
FROM Prod_Units ProdUnits
INNER JOIN PUIDLIST_CTE PUIDCTE ON ProdUnits.PU_Id IN (PUIDCTE.PU_ID)  
INNER JOIN Orders ORD ON ORD.TimeStamp BETWEEN @STARTTIME AND @ENDTIME   
                      AND ProdUnits.PU_Id IN (ORD.PU_Id)
```

Comment: Take a look at the execution plans.

Comment: @Mate, They are DateTime in both cases

Comment: @Mate That is not his problem, he is using datetime both in the column and in the variables, if the problem were related with that article then the *first* query would be slower, not the second one (also, in the first case he don't use variables, he use literals, and in SQL Server literals for dates are strings).